# Python Image Library and Gtk.FontSelectionDialog

Tags: python, fonts, gtk, python-imaging-library, pango

I want to get PIL to draw the text using their fonts to get them, I use this code:

```
fdia = Gtk.FontSelectionDialog("Font")
response = fdia.run()
if response == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:
    self.ui.eFont.set_text(fdia.get_font_name())
fdia.destroy()
```

(It's return "Impact 14", for example)

but PIL requires a full path, how to get it? I try to pango:

```
draw.text((5, 5), "exm", font=pango.FontDescription("Impact 10"),\
                                            fill="#FFFFFF")
```

but PIL says :

```
AttributeError: 'pango.FontDescription' object has no attribute 'getmask'
```

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: I also thought that would be using Pango to create an image with text and overlay it using PIL. But examples of such perversions are not found.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're going to have an easy time making Pango fonts and PIL font description classes play nice. The `Pango.FontDescription` object is not the same as the `ImageFont` object. You may want to use `Cairo` to render your fonts and graphics rather than PIL.

I have seen some folks who write to a PNG with PIL and then open that with Cairo to do font rendering--but I would just pick one or the other.